# mysql resultset is empty?

Tags: c++, mysql

**EDIT**

Followup question: [mysql resultset is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24976510/mysql-resultset-is-always-null)

--

The `resultset` seems empty and I am sure that the table exists, there is no `SQLException` thrown.
It should print the count but it doesn't.

**CDatabase Header**

```
class CDatabase
{
    bool verify(string, string);
public:
    sql::Connection *con;
    CDatabase();
    ~CDatabase();
};
```

**CDatabase::CDatabase**

```
con = driver->connect("", "", "");
con->setSchema("");
```

**CDatabase::verify**

```
bool CDatabase::verify(string channel, string hyper_key)
{
    if (!con) return false;
    try
    {
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;
        stmt = con->createStatement();
        stmt->execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dark_souls2_widgets");
        res = stmt->getResultSet();
        cout << res->rowsCount();
        delete stmt;
        delete res;
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line »" << __LINE__ << endl;
        cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you run `mysql` from a command prompt? Or if not, you can download the free MySQL GUI tools and you can you run the query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dark_souls2_widgets;` manually to confirm what you should get.

Comment: I did that and got a count of 1.

Comment: Did you try using `executeQuery` (per [MySQL Connector/C++ Fetching Results](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-results.html))?

Comment: Yes I tried that, with prepared statements aswell. Main post edited with more clarification.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't show the count, it should show `1`, cause this query will either fail or the result will have just one row. If you want to know how many rows exists in your table `dark_souls2_widgets` then you could do this with

```
res = stmt->getResultSet();

while (res->next()) {
  cout << res->getInt(1); // getInt(1) returns the first column
}
```

Comment: then there should be no connection. You can verify this with modifying your if statement, i.e. with:  if (!con) { cout << "no connection"; return false;}

Comment: I have that at the top, if it returns false it will quit the program.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used mysql with c++ in a while but I'll give this a shot... this is an example from dev.mysql

```
stmt = con->createStatement();
res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
}
```

First I notice you are using execute() instead of executeQuery(). Most important though rowsCount() will always be 1 row if it is successful, because the query returns 1 row only which has the result of your query. Try this..

```
stmt->executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dark_souls2_widgets");
res = stmt->getResultSet();
while (res->next()) {
    cout << res->getInt(1);
}
```

Or even this should work because it will select every row and output the number of rows returned

```
stmt->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM dark_souls2_widgets");
cout << res->rowsCount();
```

Edit - Try this one

```
stmt = con->creteStatement()
res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dark_souls2_widgets");
while (res->next()) {
    cout << res->getInt(1);
}
```

Comment: There is something else wrong because that outputs nothing at all.

Comment: Your code gives an acccess violation when debugging, there must be something wrong with the dll or libs?

Comment: `+  res 0x00000000 <NULL> sql::ResultSet *`

Comment: hmmm I'm not sure what is wrong then, maybe you should make that a new question

Comment: did the second block of code i posted do that as well? maybe there is nothing in res->getInt(1)