# mysql resultset is always null

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio-2013

Followup from unresolved question: [mysql resultset is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24975838/mysql-resultset-is-empty)

The resultset is always null and the connection is alive.
The VS2013 debugger says that mysqlcppconn.dll has no debugging symbols.

Tested the query on a mysql console and it worked fine, it returned `1`.

```
  CDatabase::CDatabase(CSettings* settings)
    {
        settings = settings;
        try {
            Connection* con = get_driver_instance()->connect("", "", "");
            con->setSchema("hyperbot");
            cout << "Connected." << endl << endl;
            cout << "Verifying hyper key with database...." << endl;

        if (!verify(con, settings->get_channel(), settings->get_hyper_key()))
        {
            cout << "Verification failed." << endl;
            CFunctions::ExitWithTimeout(5000);
        }
        delete con;
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line »" << __LINE__ << endl;
        cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
        CFunctions::ExitWithTimeout(5000);
    }
}

bool CDatabase::verify(Connection* con, string channel, string hyper_key)
{
    if (!con) return false;

    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res;
    stmt = con->createStatement();
    stmt->executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dark_souls2_widgets");
    res = stmt->getResultSet();
    if (res == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    while (res->next()) {
        cout << res->getInt(1);
    }
    delete stmt;
    delete res;
    /*sql::ResultSet *res;
    sql::PreparedStatement  *prep_stmt;

    prep_stmt = con->prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dark_souls2_widgets WHERE channel=? AND hyper_key=?");
    prep_stmt->setString(1, channel);
    prep_stmt->setString(2, hyper_key);
    prep_stmt->execute();
    res = prep_stmt->getResultSet();
    delete res;
    delete prep_stmt;
    */
    return false;
}

CDatabase::~CDatabase()
{
}
```

I also get these strange warnings on compile:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\mysql\mysql connector c++ 1.1.3\include\cppconn\sqlstring.h(38): warning C4251: 'sql::SQLString::realStr' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'sql::SQLString'
1>c:\program files (x86)\mysql\mysql connector c++ 1.1.3\include\mysql_driver.h(52): warning C4251: 'sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver::proxy' : class 'boost::scoped_ptr<sql::mysql::NativeAPI::NativeDriverWrapper>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver'
1>c:\program files (x86)\mysql\mysql connector c++ 1.1.3\include\mysql_connection.h(165): warning C4251: 'sql::mysql::MySQL_Connection::proxy' : class 'boost::shared_ptr<sql::mysql::NativeAPI::NativeConnectionWrapper>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'sql::mysql::MySQL_Connection'
1>c:\program files (x86)\mysql\mysql connector c++ 1.1.3\include\mysql_connection.h(169): warning C4251: 'sql::mysql::MySQL_Connection::service' : class 'boost::scoped_ptr<sql::mysql::MySQL_Statement>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'sql::mysql::MySQL_Connection'
1>c:\program files (x86)\mysql\mysql connector c++ 1.1.3\include\cppconn\exception.h(61): warning C4251: 'sql::SQLException::sql_state' : class 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'sql::SQLException'
```

Comment: Anyone?.................

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue; it's caused by those warnings. Apparently the problem is that the MySQL C++ source .lib was built using a different compiler, so we have to re-compile it using VC2013's. I'd rather not have to recompile, so I started a bounty on this question so someone tells me another way to bypass the warning ;) .

Comment: @zyboxinternational I am using VS2008 right now, take a look at: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/351316-mysql-resultset-is-always-null/page__p__2037291__fromsearch__1
Would indeed be nice to have it on VS2013, however!

Comment: Hi there: could you post more code, as it  may be that the problem lies elsewhere in your code.  For example are you trying to export any of the mysql DLL functionality ( ie defining `mysqlcppconn_EXPORTS`) anywhere?  As that is normally for creating a dll, not for use in a exe.

Comment: Do you have libmysql.dll somewhere in your path? Try to put this dll file in the folder where the executable is.

Comment: I had a similar problem a while back and it was caused by the fact that I was linking to the library built in release mode while I was running my program in debug mode. The behavior was similar to yours : everything was working "ok" except I didn't get anything back. Check if your include paths point to the correct static library for your target.

Comment: Try your program on release mode and let us know the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be related to [this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=45751)

Which basically means you may have to put

```
#define CPPCONN_LIB_BUILD 1
```

in your code. Not sure, though.